# Data Types compare and return result

Tags: ruby

based on the argument supplied to the function. Follow through the test to produce the perfect function that accounts for all expectations.

For strings, return its length.
For nil return string 'no value'
For booleans return the boolean
For numbers return a string showing how it compares to hundred e.g. For 67 return 'less than 100' for 4034 return 'more than 100'
For arrays return the 3rd index, or nil if it doesn't exist

Comment: This looks like homework. What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: kind of but not homework, my question ?

Comment: produce the perfect function that would accounts for all expectations,

Comment: For strings, return its length.
For nil return string 'no value'
For booleans return the boolean
For numbers return a string showing how it compares to hundred e.g. For 67 return 'less than 100' for 4034 return 'more than 100'
For arrays return the 3rd index, or nil if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

This is very much the same as @T.Aoukar, but less verbose.

```
def perfect(a)
  case a
    when String
      a.size
    when Array
      a[2]
    when TrueClass, FalseClass
      a
    when NilClass
      "no value"
    when Numeric
      #insert code yourself
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_a?` method to check the data type.

For example: (This is not the complete finished function, just as a reference)

```
def function(argu)
    if argu.is_a?(Integer)
       argu > 100 ? "more than 100" : "less than or equal to 100"
    elsif argu.is_a?(String)
       argu.length
    elsif [true, false].include? argu
       argu
    elsif argu.is_a?(Array)
       argu[2]
    end
end

puts function(101)
puts function(10)
puts function("abc")
puts function(true)
puts function([1,2,3])

more than 100
less than 100
3
true
3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an amazing method called `.class` that'll return the class of object (parameter), then you can use a `case` statement to check on each class and return the required function, example for `String` class:

```
def test (a)
  case a.class.to_s
    when 'String'
      return a.length
  end
end
```

note that if you use `a.class` without `.to_s` you can't use `case` but you'll have to use `if` because `case` statement is like `===` which will return false when you compare `a.class` with `String`

Hope this helps you to write your function.

Comment: not quite but at least its a start really appreciate thanks a lot ..